# What scales and or modes are used in rebetiko?

Tags: scales, modes

What scales and / or modes are traditionally used in rebetiko music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They quite often use the western major and minor scales we all use, but since it is strongly influenced by eastern civilizations, mainly from Turkey, they use eastern-inspired scales from their traditional music. Some examples are [Makam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makam), and from what I see on a quick search, among other scales they also use the [phrygian dominant scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_dominant_scale), which is called 'hijaz' in Arab and the Persian scale [Rast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rast_(maqam))